# Using SQL to copy data from worksheets to other worksheets in the same workbook?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I would like to use SQL to move data around from sheet to sheet within the same workbook.

My sheets are large (width & depth) and coping with VBA is slow.

The scenario is that I have sheets 1 to 5.
I want to create sheet(6) with a column or two from sheets 1 -5.
The index key is SKU and is common to all sheets. 
All sheets are sorted by SKU to begin with.

When I grab a column in Sheet(1) I can just put it in Sheet(6), Column A.
When I grab a column in sheet(2) I need to be sure that each row's SKU matches and that the data from sheet(2) and is correctly placed in the next column for that SKU.  If data for that SKU is not available the corresponding cell is left EMPTY.  The data from each column is kept together in one selected column in the target worksheet.

I am not certain how to set up the connection or recordset selections since we are working within the same workbook.  I cannot find this topic discussed anywhere.  Ensuring the SKU receives the correct data from all sheets seems a little daunting to me.

I seem to remember something about not being able to establish ADO connections to open workbooks/sheets.  If that is the case I will create a separate workbook to extract the data to and manipulate there.

I would really appreciate any guidance on this subject.  This is all new ground for me.

Thanks, CraigM

Comment: Long term you might want to consider moving all of this into a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution i created: 
I got sheet1, sheet2 as described as below images:
[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

To copy the by using the sql, the following code is been used: 
Note: You need go to Tools > Reference > check Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library and Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

```
Sub SQLCopy()


Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRecord As ADODB.Recordset

Set MyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set MyRecord = New ADODB.Recordset

' This is the Excel 97-2003 connection string. It should also work with
' Excel 2007 onwards worksheets as long as they have less than 65536
' rows
With MyConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

MyRecord.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[SKU],[SecondDATA] FROM [Sheet1$],[Sheet2$] WHERE " & _
    "[Sheet1$].[SKU]  = " & _
    "[Sheet2$].[SKU]", MyConnection

Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset MyRecord

MyRecord.Close
MyConnection.Close

End Sub
```

The following is the result at sheet 3 
[image: Sheet3]

Comment: .open   Runtime error '3706': Provider cannot be found.   I am using this code; With objConnection
    .Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                "Data Source=" & "F:\Temp04\2015-06-16-00, BirdFeetPricing.xlsm" & ";" & _
                                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    .Open
End With

Comment: No 64 bit is not the problem.  I have used the ACE provider in the code previously in the same program.  I am missing something here but I do not know what.

Comment: If I use the code exactly, I get "Could Not FInd Instablle ISAM."          With MyConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

Comment: @CraigM did you create the table using `Insert` > `Table` ? you can not simply enter table header and rows in the worksheets.

Comment: No I did not use the Insert>table method.  I did get the ACE connector working with the SQL statement: szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "] WHERE price <> NULL ORDER BY " & TargetSortColumn & ";"   I cannot explain why it started working but it is.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful solution, keong kenshih!

I was looking thru the Microsoft documendation and as I read it, it indicates that you cannot use SQL on open workbooks.

Thanks for the proof of concept code.  I am going to incorporate it into my project in the next couple of days.  Should provide a big performance improvement.

I will change from using the .jet provider to the .ace provider to be compatible with newer versions of Excel.

Nick.McDermaid: I cannot move all the data into a database as the data is frequently updated in Excel.  I'm lucky the client even has Excel they are so backwards.  They have no concept of a database.  They are stuck in the 1970's with Yahoo.

Thanks again for everyone's comments!

Comment: I am confused. I am running the exact code first offered by keong kenshih.   I am getting a strange error on the MyRecord statement below.  That error is: "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another". I have gone as far as to create Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3,  Sheets 1 & 2 have data on them.  MyRecord.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[SKU],[SecondDATA] FROM [Sheet1$],[Sheet2$] WHERE " & _
    "[Sheet1$].[SKU]" = "[Sheet2$].[SKU]", objConnection

Comment: I have changed my sheets to test your code.  I get an error "No Value Given for one or more required parameters".  I am lost, I cannot find much documentation on SecondData.                                                            MyRecord.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[SKU],[SecondDATA] FROM [Sheet1$],[Sheet2$] WHERE [Sheet1$].[SKU] = [Sheet2$].[SKU]", MyConnection